# Write to csv NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, export-to-csv

I am currently working on a Twitch bot for my channel.  The bot takes in commands for a ratings poll and adds the viewer's user-ID and pollEntry to a dictionary.  Once I type a command to end the poll, the dictionary keys and values need to be written to a csv on my local machine (at least that's what I want).

```js
 const csvWriter = new createCsvWriter({
                        path: `C:/the_bot/Poll_Outputs/${pollName}${dt}.csv`,
                        header: [
                            {id: 'user_ID', title: 'User ID'},
                            {id: 'rating', title: 'Rating'}
                        ]
                    })

                    for (var dict_key in dict){
                        console.log (`dict key: ${dict_key}`)
                        console.log(`Dict[dict_key]: ${dict[dict_key]}`)
                        records = [
                            {user_ID: dict_key, rating: dict[dict_key]}
                        ]  
                    }
                    try {
                        csvWriter.writeRecords(records)
                        .then(() => {
                            console.log(`...CSV write Done`)
                        })
                    }
                    catch{
                        console.log(`Error: ${TypeError}`)
                    }
```

When the dict is unpacked to load into the variable records, each key and value logs correctly in the console but the actual output shows only one record.

```js
for (var dict_key in dict){
                    console.log (`dict key: ${dict_key}`)
                    console.log(`Dict[dict_key]: ${dict[dict_key]}`)
                    records = [
                        {user_ID: dict_key, rating: dict[dict_key]}
                    ]  
                }
```

Hopefully I'm clear enough, please help.

Stuugie

Comment: Yes, `records = […]` overwrites the `records` variable in every iteration with a new array that contains a single element.

Comment: You update the `records` variable to a single entry on each iteration, instead create the array outside of the loop and push the item on each iteration

Comment: @King Stuugie can you specify what is the package that you are using? Where does the `createCsvWriter` come from?

Comment: @ross-u The createCsvWriter comes from const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter

Comment: @AsafAviv thanks, I will give that a go.